# How do I get the difference between the main branch and the pull request one in Azure DevOps pipeline?

Tags: git, powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to get new/changed PowerShell files between 2 branches. From the main one and the one I'm doing pull request from in Azure DevOps pipeline with:

```
$changedFiles = (git diff --cached --name-only | Where-Object { $_ -like "*.ps1" })
```

yet I don't get any while the command works locally. I assume it needs to change the location in pipeline, but I after trying to locate some repository file i can't find it. It should download the files before it's being executed?
Some more code fragments:

pre-commit.ps1

```
Get-Location # returns D:\a\1\s
Get-ChildItem # returns nothing
gci -recurse -filter "test.ps1" # returns nothing
$changedFiles = (git diff --cached --name-only | Where-Object { $_ -like "*.ps1" })
$exitCode = 0
$changedFiles # returns none

if ($changedFiles.length -eq 0) {
    exit $exitCode
}
else{
   ...
}
```

azure-pipelines.yml

```
trigger:
- main

jobs:
 - job: RunScript
   pool:
     vmImage: windows-2019
   steps:
     - powershell:
         .\pre-commit.ps1
```

**UPDATE**:

```
$files = (git diff --name-only HEAD HEAD~1 | Where-Object {$_ -match '\w*.ps[m]?1' })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git diff --cached` will only display differences between the index (the files staged using `git add`) and the current commit.
While it may show modifications in your working copy (on your working computer, you may be in a state you have modified and staged files before committing them), it will generally not work in a copy run in a CI pipeline (in general, the actions in a CI pipeline do not involve modifying code files and running `git add`, for example).

---

If you want to list the files modified between commits `eacf11` and `eacf22`, drop the `--cached` option and simply run :

```sh
git diff --name-only eacf11 eacf22
```

You may also reference commits by a tag name or a branch name, ans also use `HEAD` to say "current commit" :

```sh
git diff --name-only master HEAD
git diff --name-only v1.2.1 eacf22
```